# Cron job running but not establishing tunnel

Tags: shell-script, cron, ssh-tunneling

I have a script which establishes a reverse tunnel on an endpoint `HostB`. It looks like this:

`cat tun.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Test code
/usr/bin/ssh -V 1> /home/userA/bin/tun.stdout 2> /home/userA/bin/tun.stderr

# Establish tunnel
createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -R *:19999:localhost:22 userB@hostB
}

# Do nothing if tunnel is already established
/usr/bin/ssh -p 19999 userA@hostB true
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    createTunnel
fi
```

when I run it manually like `./tun.sh` it works, and I can see on HostB, that userA is logged in.
If I run it again on HostA but from another console, it works as expected - it does not launch a second tunnel.

Everything so far is good.

I now edit my crontab to look like this:

`crontab -l`

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 *   *   *   *   /home/userA/bin/tun.sh
```

It runs the script every minut. This should be fine, since the script terminates if the tunnel is already established.

However, now userA does not get logged in as when I run it manually from the console.

The test code in the top of the script confirms that the script is being called, and that it has permission to execute `/usr/bin/ssh`:

`~/bin$ ls`

```
tun.sh  tun.stderr  tun.stdout
```

`~/bin$ cat tun.stderr`

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

`~/bin$ cat tun.stdout`

```
[empty]
```

For some reason `-V` writes to `stderr` and not `stdout`, but that is a detail. The main point is here that the script is being executed every minute.

My question is: **why is the SSH tunnel not established?**

Comment: I see an unquoted globbing character in `/usr/bin/ssh -R *:19999:localhost:22 userB@hostB`... Need not be the problem but that is a quite direct way to shell hell.

Comment: Does your SSH key have a password?

Comment: if you’re using ssh-agent, you need the cron job to have the evironment variables to let it find the ssh-agent process

Comment: `ssh-agent` seems to be the right pointer. I will post an answer when I have set this up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Andrew for pointing to `ssh-agent`. As far as I can see, if one wants to be able to establish the tunnel without having to enter a password each time, the password must be stored or removed. I chose to remove it. For the record, here are some clean-ups based on the comments I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Establish tunnel
createTunnel() {
    /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/laptopuser/.ssh/id_rsa_tunnel -R 2200:localhost:22 vpsuser@vps.com
}

# Do nothing if tunnel is already established
/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/user/laptopuser/.ssh/id_rsa_tunnel -p 2200 laptopuser@vps.com true
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    createTunnel
fi
```

crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 *   *   *   *   /home/laptopuser/bin/establishTunnel.sh
```

copy your tunnel id to the vps:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/laptopuser/.ssh/id_rsa_tunnel vps.com
```

wait until tunnel is running (see `sudo watch grep CRON /var/log/syslog`) and copy your normal id if you have not already got in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

```
ssh-copy-id vps.com -p 2200
```

Ideally the tunnel would run as dedicated user both on the vps and the laptop.

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem - ssh tunnel works if executed from script but not from crontab. ssh looks for keys and known_hosts in $HOME/.ssh.
If you're running the script from bash under user tom, $HOME will be /home/tom. If the script is run from crontab the user will be root and $HOME will be /home/root (or undefined).

Solution: Define HOME in your script for the user that has the keys.

```
HOME=/home/tom
```

Comment: The user that a cron job is run as depends on whose crontab the job is specified in. Cron jobs belonging to ordinary users are not run by root. That would be a severe security risk.